# meaning: laps a period

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

What does "lap" mean in the following?

> Despite the positive initial investor reaction, some analysts noted that Amazon faces an uphill battle in the coming quarters, as it combats rising costs and **laps a period** in which people may have been more reliant on online shopping before Covid-19 vaccines were widely available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means to be one year after a period of time.

It's a metaphor.  Imagine a runner going around a track.  Perhaps on one lap it is easy for the runner (there is a tailwind, for example) but the next time the runner reaches the same point there is no tailwind.  Then the second time the runner reaches that point on the lap, they will be slower.

This time last year, Amazon had a tailwind, because people were forced to shop online.  This year (one year-long lap later) people can go out to shop. So this year's sales figures will look bad by comparison.

To lap literally means to run (or ride, drive etc) a distance of one lap, or one lap more than another runner.

> The runners have now lapped eight times, only four-and-a-half more laps to go.

> The lead runner has lapped the tail runner.